# Javascript - no repeat image

Tags: javascript

I have this code in JavaScript and this images 1-6 are still repeating. But I want when it is on 6 it stop and no repeat. How can i do it?

```
<script>
     function displayNextImage2() {
              y = (y === images2.length - 1) ? 0 : y + 1;
              document.getElementById("img2").src = images2[y];
          }

          function displayPreviousImage2() {
              y = (y <= 0) ? images2.length - 1 : y - 1;
              document.getElementById("img2").src = images2[y];
          }

          function startTimer2() {
              setInterval(displayNextImage2, 5000);
          }

          var images2 = [], y = 0;
          images2[0] = "images/one.PNG";
          images2[1] = "images/two.PNG";
          images2[2] = "images/three.PNG";
          images2[3] = "images/four.PNG";
          images2[4] = "images/five.PNG";
          images2[5] = "images/six.PNG";
</script>
```

Thank for every answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the `displayNextImage2` method to

```
function displayNextImage2() 
{
  if ( y <= images2.length - 1 )
  {
     document.getElementById("img2").src = images2[y];
     y++;
     clearInterval(timer2);
  }
}
```

ensure that you clear the interval as well, so you need to keep a reference of it

```
var timer2 = "";
function startTimer2() 
{
     timer2 =   setInterval(displayNextImage2, 5000);
}
```

it won't repeat after it reaches the last image